# Git Extensions + Git For Windows: Fetching Branch that does not exist Locally does not Create New Local Branch

Tags: git, git-extensions

I'm running Git Extensions 2.32 on Git For Windows (previously known as msysgit) 1.7.10.msysgit.1.

Another user has created a new branch and pushed it to the remote repository.  I want to fetch that new branch down to my local repository.

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoQaq.png) shows what I'm trying to do.  The master is currently checked out and the other user has added a new branch, "brentfo", which he has pushed up the remote repository.  I want to now fetch that new branch down to my local repository.

I open the Git Extensions Pull dialog, as seen in the image.  I'm pulling from the origin with merge option "Do not merge, only fetch remote changes", selecting the new Remote branch "brentfo".  When I click on the Pull button I get a progress dialog:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --progress "origin" +refs/heads/brentfo
Done
From //dnzchfile1/git-chch$/mRouteDotNET
 * branch            brentfo    -> FETCH_HEAD
```

The progress dialog does not show any error.  It appears the process completes normally.

The FETCH_HEAD file shows the following:

```
eea033921fea43acf34a5baa380d1666181b56aa        branch 'master' of //server/gitrepo/mRouteDotNET
5e0640e42d04a744aae2e95663a13c0747cacaf1    not-for-merge   branch 'brentfo' of //server/gitrepo/mRouteDotNET
934e6034c526b703ac69b26497e0131f9bb71c2c    not-for-merge   branch 'mRoutePCLib' of //server/gitrepo/mRouteDotNET
```

When I look at the commit log afterwards, however, nothing seems to have happened (the commit log appears in the background in the image of the Pull dialog, above).  The new branch, brentfo, has not been created in my local repository.  When I pull down the dropdown list of branches there are still only two: master and mRoutePCLib.

I get the same result if, in the Pull dialog, I don't select any Remote branch (ie leave it blank).  In that case the progress dialog shows:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --progress "origin" 
Done
```

There appears to have once been a bug to do with creating local branches from remote ones in earlier versions of Git Extensions.  However, looking at the Git Extensions project [change log](https://github.com/spdr870/gitextensions/blob/master/GitUI/Resources/ChangeLog.txt) the problem looks like it was solved way back in version 1.55.  So I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong.

I know I can use the Git Bash console to fetch the remote branch and create a new local one from it.  However, it seems to be I should be able to do this via the GUI.

I'm hoping for answers along the lines of either:

a) Yes, you're doing it wrong and here's how you should do it (via the GUI); or

b) This is a known issue, you'll have to do it from the command-line interface (Git Bash) until the bug is fixed.

Cheers
Simon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fetching will just bring in all the changes in the current branch (and locally tracked branches? someone help me on this one.) and the *knowledge* of all the remote branches. You really don't want fetch to bring down all the commits for all the branches that you haven't checked out yet.. That would be bad if there were thousands of branches. For checking out remote branches that you can't see yet, you Fetch then Checkout Branch.

You already fetched the existence of the remote branch.

Now you want to do

Git Extensions -> Checkout Branch

Change it from Local to Remote. Pick the remote branch in the drop down. Say ok, it will ask if you want to create a local branch then track it. Make sure to click Yes.

I recommend finding some way to buy Smart Git 3. It is by far better than all the other Windows Git products. They have a free Open Source license version.

Comment: I suspect the real problem here is that I don't have a good understanding of the underlying git API, rather than there being something wrong with Git Extensions.  For most things I've found Git Extensions to be really good.  Have been using it for a month or so and everything has been smooth sailing, apart from submodules.  Even with submodules I get the impression Git Extensions handles things better than the command-line interface (eg can you remove a submodule via the CLI yet?).  It seems, though, git is the equivalent of C++ for SCMs - easy to screw up if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: @SimonTewsi The big hurdle most people have is 1. Git doesn't care about individual files. 2. You are always working locally for everything you do. It took me a while before I realized how Fetch, Pull and Checkout relate to each other. It is also pretty easy to make a mess of things with Git. But I haven't found a mess that cannot also be fixed. All else fails rewrite the history and tell all the other developers they must re-clone. Rewriting history is the absolute last resort and requires all other participants to redo their local repo.

Comment: The problem is not knowing what I don't know.  I thought I understood the difference between pull and fetch but I've never come across checking out a remote branch before.  I think I need to go back and do some sort of tutorial to fill in the holes in my knowledge.  One good thing I find with git is that I can just take a copy of a local repo and experiment with it, knowing I have another copy if I screw things up.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell, what fetching does heavily depends on whether `git fetch` was given any refspec(s) or what is configured in the "fetch" configuration option for the given remote from which fetching is done when no refspecs are specified explicitly.  For the most common case (fetching w/o explicit refspecs + the standard refspec in the `.git/config` for the given remote), fetching just brings all the heads (branches) from the remote and (forcibly) updates matching local remote-tracking branches, creating those that do not exist yet.

Answer (score 2):

Further to Andrew Finnell's answer:

After selecting **Git Extensions > Checkout branch** (from Windows Explorer context menu), the **Checkout Branch dialog** will open.

Select **Remote branch** and the name of the remote branch to pull down and click **Checkout**.  The **Checkout Remote Branch dialog** will open.

In the Checkout Remote Branch dialog, select **Reset local branch with the name '{branch name}'** and make sure **Merge** is checked, then click **Checkout**:

[image: Checkout Remote Branch dialog]

This will create a new local branch, update it with the changes from the remote branch, and create a mapping between the local branch and the remote branch so that changes can be pushed and pulled between them.

**NOTE:**  Don't select "Create local branch with the name '{remote name}_{branch name}'".  This will create a local branch but it will be prefixed with the name of the remote repository (in the example above the local branch would be named "origin_DSIChanges" instead of "DSIChanges").

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're doing it wrong and here's how you should do it (via the GUI);
You are fetching Remote branch commits to your local branch but You need to merge remote branch with Local branch also. Please select "Merge remote branch into current branch" option never select "Only fetch Do not merge".